# Increase sensitivity of Trackpad?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

I currently have the sensitivity level to the max, but I still feel its kind of slow for my liking. Is there a way I can make the trackpad on my rMBP even more sensitive ?

Comment: system Preferences > Trackpad > Tracking Speed is set to the max and it's still "kind of slow"? I think something's wrong with your computer!

Comment: It is kind of slow for my own preference. I used to have a very high sensitive mouse before and would like to keep it that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setting in System Preferences changes the `com.apple.trackpad.scaling` key in `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences`. You can also edit it manually:

```
defaults write -g com.apple.trackpad.scaling -float 5.0
```

The normal minimum and maximum values are 0.0 and 3.0. You have to log out and back in to apply the changes. Moving the slider in System Preferences resets the setting.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutety, I'm using [Better Touch Tool](http://blog.boastr.net/) for a very long time now, and I can't imagine using my Magic Mouse or Touchpad without it anymore. The maximum pointer speed provided by OS X is simply not sufficient (especially for the Magic Mouse). And there's so much more you can do with the hardware (lots of options in the tool).